# Element - DatePicker without input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datepicker, element, element-ui

I'm trying to display the [Element Datepicker](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/date-picker) component directly in my Vue page, without having to display and click on the input element for it to popup. I read their [source code](https://github.com/ElemeFE/element/tree/dev/packages/date-picker) on Github, there is no prop for this, and I don't want to modify it on my project in node_modules as I know it's bad practice.

I tried to append the div created by the click event directly into my vue but it's not working and I can't manage to track and retrieve my input data to my Vuejs state.

Here is a screenshot of the div created by the Datepicker input click event :

[image]

If anyone has any idea on how to achieve this, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ref` to call a function on the picker component

```
<el-date-picker
      ref="test"
      v-model="value1"
      type="date"
      placeholder="Pick a day">
</el-date-picker>
```

JS

```
mounted() {
  this.$refs.test.showPicker()
},
```

Also added a example on codepen: https://codepen.io/reijnemans/pen/ExmvGLa